# Can't use get_post_meta() inside a hook function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm using `{status}_{post_type}` hook and need to grab a custom meta from the post:

```
add_action( 'pending_book', function( $post_id, $post ) {
    $foo = get_post_meta($post_id, 'book_author', true);
    var_dump($foo);
}, 99, 2 );
```

But it return `string(0) ""`

The post was generated in frontend, using GravityForms.

What can I do?

Comment: Check you are getting the correct post id - dump that out. Then try the get_post_meta query using that id and see what you get. If you still get nothing then it is likely either the meta name is wrong or there simply is no data.

Comment: @SimonPollard Everything is fine. The problem is hook. I solve the problem using `gform_after_submission` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: GravityForm hook

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_13', function( $entry, $form ) {
    $foo = get_post_meta($entry['post_id'], 'book_author', true);
    var_dump($foo);
}, 10, 2 );
```

Where 13 is the ID of form.

More info here: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/